# How to use a variable scope properly so I don't have to use "$_GET"

Tags: php, variables, scope

I'm not even sure if 'variable scope' is the right term. I basically have a form submitted that sets variables. I then redirect conditionally based on some of them, then I need to retrieve some of them again. Currently, it works if I pass them as a Query String and receive via `$_GET`. I'd use `$_POST` but it's not the very next page.

I've got a Form page, the reloaded form page which forwards to a landing page. On the landing page, its `www.domain.com/landingpage?foo=bar`. I'd like a better method.

on the form, i've got

```
if(isset($_POST['foo'])){ $foo = $_POST['foo']; } else { $foo = ''; }
```

because I need the variables set always, even if there's an error/blank field.

Then I redirect to

```
http://www.domain.com/landing?foo=bar
```

and retrieve `$_GET['foo']`.

On the form page, how do I set the variable for use on the latter PHP pages?

Comment: Session Variables might do the trick?

Comment: you could try a session variable or a cookie.

Comment: Cookies would only work if the user agent allows them tho, correct? So would a Session Variable be a more 'reliable' way to go about it?

Comment: Session variables are dependent on cookies (to identify the correct session to use).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to utilize PHP sessions [by the way, variable scope isn't the right word].
Call `session_start()` at the top of each file, and then you can set variables in the `$_SESSION` superglobal which will persist across pages.